# Which template for my iOS project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode-template

I'm about to create a new application and wanted to know what template to start with for the following functionality and any key pointers you can provide for a beginner would be really appreciated!

Starts with splash screen and goes to first view
UITabBarController at the bottom and header at the top for every view

First view - textbox, submit button, 2 items in a table which sends the user to a sub-view
Second view - a list of items which once clicked take the user to a view which can also take them to a subview
Third view - a list of items which once clicked take the user to a view which can also take them to a subview
Fourth view - a search function, displays a list and once clicked take the user to a view which can also take them to a subview
Fifth view - a list of items which once clicked take the user to a view which can also take them to a subview

Thank you!

Comment: As an addendum to this question, I suggest that the answers describe the intended use of the different project templates.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter, because you can basically make any app out of any template (they're not *that* different), but the "Tab Bar Application" template is probably a good start for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! So do I start off with Tab Bar and within each view I can tell it which to use?

Answer (score 0):

`Navigation based application` or `Tab Bar Application` seem to suit your needs. This template provides a starting point for an application that uses a navigation controller. It provides a user interface configured with a navigation controller to display a list of items.

or if you want to control creation of all the views, you can start with `View-based application` and do the navigation yourself. This template provides a starting point for an application that uses a single view. It provides a view controller to manage the view, and a nib file that contains the view.

All the best...

Comment: Thank you! So the nib file is the .xib file? Or is the .xib file just the design view file? Thanks for your comments, much appreciated!

Comment: xib is an XML format which gets compiled into the older native nib format.

Answer (score 0):

Window-based application. It'll pay off in the end learning to create your views without Interface Builder. Besides, there's LOADS of tutorials on how to do things without Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any links for tutorials on creating things without Interface builder?

Comment: Apple's UICatalog (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project is great because it implements many different types of views and controls, all programmatically. Of course, some web searches on specific things will still turn up results.